# Append values to querystring using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append values to a querystring using jQuery, problem I'm having is that the values are getting duplicated as shown below.

```
?id=na&val1=/?id=na&val1=Ring&val2=/?id=na&val2=Gold
```

What I really want is ?id=na&val1=ring&val2=Gold

My code is:

```
 $("#Type").change(function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem("Type1", $(this).val());
        location.href = "/?id=na&val1=" + sessionStorage.getItem("Type1") + "&val2=" + sessionStorage.getItem("Type2");
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated
Type is below:

```
<select id="Type" name="Type"><option value="">Type</option>
<option value="/?id=na">Ring1</option>
<option value="/?id=na">Ring</option>
</select>
```

Just an update, I have 3 selects, a visitor can select the value from the 1st select which will do a page refresh and update the content on the page.

The visitor can then select an option from the 2nd select which changes with the values of the 1st select and I need to then pass the value of select 1 and the 2nd select with a full page refresh that then updates the values in the 3rd select.

I can get the code to work if only doing 1 update at a time, but I'm having problems when trying to filter based on the 3 selects.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: What is `#Type`? Can you show the HTML for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do people mark a question down without explaining why the markdown. It seems to happen a lot on SO lately if someone does not know how to do something help them. We have all been in situations where time is against us and we don't have time to Google looking for the answer which could be the situation here.

Paul Thompson, your select list, replace with the following

```
<select id="Type" name="Type"><option value="">Type</option>
<option value="ring1">Ring1</option>
<option value="ring">Ring</option>
</select>
```

Then you can do the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var type1Value;
var type2Value;
var type3Value;

$("#Type1").change(function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem("Type1", $(this).val());
        location.href = "/?id=na&Type1=" + $(this).val();
    });

$("#Type2").change(function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem("Type2", $(this).val());

        if (sessionStorage.getItem("Type1") === null) {
            type1Value = "na";
        } else {
            type1Value = sessionStorage.getItem("Type1");
        }

        if (sessionStorage.getItem("Type2") === null) {
            type2Value = "na";
        } else {
            type2Value = sessionStorage.getItem("Type2");
        }

        location.href = "/?id=na&type1=" + type1Value + "&type2=" + type2Value;
    });
 });
```

So you say you have 3 select lists, so do the same for the 3rd, then when you make select list changes, the url will change with the values supplied.